# How to display articles through a file, but not specify it in the URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Now I output articles through the article.php file, in htaccess there is such a code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1/$0 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ article.php [L]
```

This way I get a readable URL like site.ru/article/123/. 123 - article id

The question is: how can I drop the word article in the url and display the article through site.ru/123/, using the same article.php file?

Comment: Remove the `article/` part from the RewriteRule, and add two RewriteConds before it that check if what was requested was not a physically existing folder or file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do is using the `RewriteRule` as follows where it detects the URL with 'article' and redirects to a new link.

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: It will redirect to the correct URL needed. Hopefully you have the appropritate logic in place necessary for the new URL to work.